# Windows 7 object manager - object type structures

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

Within the Windows 7 Object Manager system, objects are created to serve a specific purpose.

So for instance devices are by the _device_object structure

Drivers use the _driver_object structure

However, I'm trying to determine which structure is used for objects of the type 'Key', which are objects that represent opened registry keys.

I know that the _file_object structure is used to represent most things, but from what I've seen I don't think it's used to represent Key objects.

If anyone has any information, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

---***UPDATE***---

Thanks to sergmat for his quick answer.  It seems the structure I was looking for was _CM_KEY_BODY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lkd> dt nt!*cm*key*
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_HASH_TABLE_ENTRY
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_SECURITY_CACHE_ENTRY
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_CONTROL_BLOCK
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_HASH
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_SECURITY_CACHE
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_BODY
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_NODE
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_VALUE
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_SECURITY
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_INDEX
      ntkrnlmp!_CM_KEY_REFERENCE
```

Description in [Windows Internals 6-1](http://books.google.com/books?id=3NBI1vvQO60C&pg=PT597&dq=cm_key_node&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=KRhoUtmMF-mk4gSAioAI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cm_key_node&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the info sergmat.  So I'm hoping that one of these bad boys will be within the 'Key' object I'm currently looking at?